# Drools fusion not firing rules in the case of new event

Tags: java, drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I am working on drools fusion 6.2 final and want to fire rules in the case of new event in stream mode. But rules are not getting fired at its own.

My rules file content is as follows:

```
//created on: May 8, 2015
package com.test

import com.test.Applicant
declare Applicant
   @role(event)
end

rule "Your First Rule"
when
    accumulate( $st : Applicant(age: age) over window:time(10ms) from      entry-point X , $c: average ( age ) )
then
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~avg~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println($c);
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~avg~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
end
```

And the code as follows:

```
package com.test;

import org.kie.api.KieBaseConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSessionConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.runtime.conf.ClockTypeOption;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.EntryPoint;
import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBase;
import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DroolsTest {


    public DroolsTest() {
        KieBaseConfiguration config_time = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
        config_time.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("test.drl", getClass()), ResourceType.DRL);
        if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("EERRRRRRRROOOOOORRRR");
            System.out.println(kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
            System.out.println("EERRRRRRRROOOOOORRRR");
        }

        KieBaseConfiguration kBaseConfig = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();

        KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(kBaseConfig);
        kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());

        KieSessionConfiguration conf = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeSessionConfiguration();
        conf.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("REALTIME"));
        final StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(conf, null);
        final EntryPoint atmStream = ksession.getEntryPoint("X");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP  " + i);
            Applicant applicant = new Applicant("Mr John Smith " + i, i);
            atmStream.insert(applicant);
//          ksession.fireAllRules();
        }
        ksession.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DroolsTest();
    }

}
```

Rules are getting fired when called deliberately, but failed to fire in the case of new event on the stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call fireAllRules you won't see any effect of rules. Uncomment this line:

```
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Although, running the session with repeated calls of fireAllRules isn't the best way. Better is to use a thread for calling fireUntilHalt, e.g.

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            kieSession.fireUntilHalt();
        }
    }.start();
```

and insert events from another thread, e.g., from a loop while simulating events and the passage of time using Thread.sleep or reading events from an external source.

Comment: But I want to do complex event processing on the basis of sliding window. And calling fireAllRules every time won't work.

Comment: I've shown you the alternative: using fireUntilHalt in a separate thread is the way to do it.

Comment: In the above rule code time based window is defined. So the solution to use thread is not working

Comment: It seems that you don't understand Drools CEP. Believe me, it *is* working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 KieBaseConfigurations Defined. config_time.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);  is set for streaming but never used.

Try setting EventProcessingOption.STREAM on the kBaseConfig that you actually use.